# Continuity/Inverse in Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d1)$and $(Y,d2)$ be topological spaces and suppose $f:X → Y$ is continuous on $X$ and $B ⊆ Y$.

Prove or provide a counterexample for a and b.

a.  $f^{−1}(Int(B)) ⊆ Int(f^{−1} (B))$

b. $ Int(f^{-1} (B)) ⊆ f^{−1} (Int(B))$

For a., I stated that $Int(B)$ is open in $Y$ so  $f^{-1} (Int(B))$ is open in $X$.  Since $f^{−1} (Int(B))⊆f−1(B)$ and $Int(f^{−1} (B))$ is the greatest open set containing $f^{-1} (B)$.  Thus, $f^{−1} (Int(B)) ⊆ Int(f^{−1} (B))$.

For b., I feel like it is false but I'm struggling to prove it or find a clear counterexample.

Comment: What is $B$?...

Comment: As it is written now, the statement "$f$ is continuous if and only if $B \subseteq Y$" does not make sense. Maybe you wanted to say that "$f$ is continuous and $B \subseteq Y$ is a subset"?

Comment: @Crostul you are correct.  I fixed it.

Comment: @Rise the question never identifies a B.  Simply states that B is a subset of Y.

Answer (score 1):

Condition a) should say: $$\forall B \subseteq Y: f^{-1}[\operatorname{Int}(B)] \subseteq \operatorname{Int}(f^{-1}[B]) \text{     (a) }$$

And you gave a proof that $f$ continuous implies condition (a) (**not** (b)!): the left hand side is open by continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}[\operatorname{Int}(B)] \subseteq f^{-1}[B]$ so by maximality of the interior we have the inclusion.

The reverse also holds (s0o the condition is equivalent to continuity of $f$): let (a) hold and suppose $O \subseteq Y$ be open. Then (a) says

$$f^{-1}[O] = f^{-1}[\operatorname{Int}(O)] \subseteq \operatorname{Int}(f^{-1}[O]) \subseteq f^{-1}[O]$$

so $\operatorname{Int}(f^{-1}[O]) = f^{-1}[O]$ is so $f^{-1}[O]$ is open. Hence $f$ is continuous.

Condition b) should say:

$$\forall B \subseteq Y: \operatorname{Int}(f^{-1}[B]) \subseteq f^{-1}[\operatorname{Int}(B)] \text{ (b) }$$

As (a) was true, this suggests looking for a counterexample.

A particularly easy one: let $f$ be a constant function, say with value $0$,from the reals to itself. Then $f$ is continuous, but for $B = \{0\}$ we have $\operatorname{Int}(B) = \emptyset$ and so is its inverse image.

But $f^{-1}[B] = \mathbb{R}$ which has itself as the interior. So (b) would say $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \emptyset$, which is nonsense.